# How to fix logo display in header?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am unable to upload an image to my header - logo section.

here is the following code is showing

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["url"]=> string(0) "" ["width"]=> string(0) "" ["height"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Where do I need to fix this?

take a look on the error here http://u208235433.hostingerapp.com/

The theme developer was trying to fix images not displaying and couldnt. I did by adding a plugin however, he/she had added this code to the site whilst trying to fix it and hasn't responded since ahhh pls help

I've tried copying and pasting the css coding from the theme files to overwrite any changes they may have done. Does not work.

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["url"]=> string(0) "" ["width"]=> string(0) "" ["height"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: Please format your code. It is not readable

Comment: An edit is already pending there.

Comment: @MCD check your theme header file, there should be a `var_dump` function being called to display this code.

Comment: the link in the image does not work

Comment: Somewhere in your theme's header file or in some other file var_dump or print_r will be there just remove anyone of them.